# Aggregate and find most used room by customer using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to find all bookings grouped by my customers, and only showing the most used room by them (and the count booked).

This is the query I have so far, but the problem is that it will show all their bookings and counts, I'm only interested in their most booked room, I'm not sure what the best function to use to achieve this. I thought querying by the `account` table and then a subquery for getting the booking numbers but I feel this might be less efficient (especially as we have around 10M account records).

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
    room_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    room_name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE bookings (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id int,
    room_id int
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO rooms (room_id, room_name)
VALUES ('1', 'Suite A'), 
('2', 'Suite B'),
('3', 'Suite C'),
('4', 'Suite D'),
('5', 'Suite X');

INSERT INTO bookings (account_id, room_id)
VALUES ('123', '1'), 
('123', '1'),
('123', '1'),
('123', '1'),
('123', '1'),
('123', '2'),
('123', '3'),
('123', '4'),
('123', '4'),
('123', '5'),
('123', '1'),
('124', '4'),
('124', '5'),
('124', '1');
```

Query:

```
select account_id, count(room_id), room_id
from bookings
group by account_id, room_id
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sTp4FrpQQoWHJvmYkKu2DD/0)

Desired Output:

```
account_id | most booked room | count
123        | Room A           | 2
124        | Room B           | 30
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* would clarify what you want.  I'm not sure why you set up a MySQL fiddle for a question tagged tsql.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the desired output, tsql wasn't supported in the tool used but the question is for tsql not mysql hence the tags used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the most common room per account.  Statistically, this is called the *mode*.

You can calculate it using window functions:

```
select ar.*
from (select account_id, room_id, count(*) as cnt, 
             row_number() over (partition by account_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from bookings
      group by account_id, room_id
     ) ar
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayBhz9pWAJW4oRLyzHRiqz/0) is the dbfiddle, using MySQL 8, so the syntax is more compatible with SQL Server.

Comment: In the event where there is an account with equal number of bookings in a venue... what is the output? and is it possible to say order by last `bookings.order_date`

Comment: Can you also explain what the `partition` and `over` functions are doing here, I'd like to understand how this works. Thanks!

Comment: @Imran . . . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  If there are equal numbers, then an arbitrary matching value is returned.  For the most recent room, you can use `order by count(*) desc, max(order_date) desc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

**[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNedhkY8AHSYcVEVmrSV8q/0)**

```
select * from
(select account_id, count(room_id) as cnt, room_id
from bookings
group by account_id, room_id
)A inner join rooms on A.room_id=rooms.room_id
where cnt in (select max(cnt) from
                (select account_id, count(room_id) as cnt, room_id
from bookings
group by account_id, room_id
)B where A.account_id=B.account_id)
```

Comment: In the demo provided this still shows more than one instance of each `account_id`

Comment: it's because of your sample data - you can see that for 124 you've entered 1, 4, 5 room - so the room no is unique here, so for each room the count is one - in this case which one you want to pick

Comment: @fa06 whenever I tries to access the demo it redirects to the homepage of dbfiddle

Comment: @SanalSunny - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hNedhkY8AHSYcVEVmrSV8q/0 - you need to exeute the query